# How to resolve sonar warning after 7.9LTS version upgrade

Tags: sonarqube

Warning:Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of source files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can be provided using sonar.java.libraries property.

Answer (score 1):

This warning comes when you are doing sonar analysis of any java project.

In order to resolve the warning message, you need to include `sonar.java.libraries` alongwith othsr sonar.analysis properties.

Value for `sonar.java.libraries`: Comma-separated paths to files with third-party libraries (JAR or Zip files) used by your project. Wildcards can be used: sonar.java.libraries=path/to/Library.jar,directory/**/*.jar

After adding this property, re-run your sonar analysis and you can then see there will be no warning message in sonarqube.